# ShowDialog Compiled for x86 Displays Behind Main Form on x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, x86, 64-bit

I've got an application that has to be compiled to x86 because of some old COM controllers to very old 3rd party software drivers.

I have noticed that anytime I call a Form's Modal Dialog Box while some other application has focus (like the Visual Studio code that I am stepping through), that Dialog Box is brought up **behind** the parent window.

```
private string Locate(string filename) {
  if (!File.Exists(filename)) {
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog()) {
      dlg.FileName = filename;
      if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
        return dlg.FileName;
      }
    }
  }
  return filename;
}
```

I can compile the application as x64, but loading the COM drivers will fail, causing the application to never start.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior from (Visual Studio, the .NET Framework, or Windows 7)? If not, then I must have something screwy going on in my code elsewhere.

Is there a way to "fix" it?

Comment: What is `this`? Where is the `Locate` method defined? It looks to me like you're getting ownership of the modal dialog wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 defaults to x86 so your configuration is quite common which would suggest you do have something screwy going on with your code.

Are you sure that ***this*** as in dlg.ShowDialog(this) is actually the parent and is visible etc?

Is Locate being called from a non-UI thread?  If not, did you try using dlg.ShowDialog().

Comment: I swapped my `this` objects around, and about half of my forms seem to be working much better! You wouldn't know how to do this same thing for displaying a [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx) when I override the [Installer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx), would you?

Comment: Haven't really used MessageBoxes in any InstallerClass routines, but I would have expected the standard calls, for example MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons),  to work - unless you are doing something like running background threads in your install routine. If so, and if you do know the parent window handle, there are overloads such as Show  (window, message, caption, buttons) that you can use.